Scan Card Payment like Visa Card, Union Pay Card using Vision framewok
enter image description here
I would like scan card number, placeholder name , and expired date in Card Payment.
I see other dependcies and libraries on the internet but some can't able to scan with 3d text like image above.
Anyway, I want to try with Vision framework by using Text Detection. Does anyone know and has experienced on it?
enter image description here
Above here is my expected image, I scan from Apple payment and shipping in my Apple Account.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
